# reason to map os code in the same logical space?

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system, kernel

I do not understand if there is some reason to map
os modules with code (for example in win32, i do not
know how it is on the other systems) in the same 
logical space as the running user proces. Wouldnt
it be better/more clear, not to map all modules 
into large space but just some jump table of 
kernell calls or something like that. Is there some
reason to map it all into large area ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 32-bit Linux for example, the address space is typically configured so that the userspace task has the bottom 3GB of virtual address space, and the kernel has the top 1GB.  The advantage here is that on entering a system call, the page tables do not need to be changed - so no TLB flushes, and the kernel can do efficient memory accesses to the userspace task (with appropriate pointer validation).